# Remove additional white space on left and right side of Angular Chart

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js, angular-chart

How to remove the white space marked in red?

[image]

I wanted the chart to display like this

[image]

I am using ionic framework, please find my below

```
<div class = "row responsive-sm">
  <div class = "item col col-50" >
      <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" style="padding: 10" 
        chart-data="data" chart-options="options" chart-labels="labels">
      </canvas> 
  </div>
  <div class = "item col" >
            <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="data" chart-options="options" chart-labels="labels">
      </canvas> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add width attribute to you canvas element

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or similar please?

Answer (score 2):

you have to provide width & height in canvas like this...

```
<canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="myChart"></canvas>
```